# How can I maintain downloads after my app goes into the background?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

My iPhone app downloads files from a server. When I exit to the background, wait a certain time, and bring it back to the foreground, I'm seeing the error `Internet connection failed`.

How can I avoid this error with my downloads when it goes to the background?

Answer (score 0):

A iPhone task has a certain amount of time it can complete its job, after it is closed. If it does not, it will be killed.

C.f.: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3